# What is meant by "collective behavior" in the definition of plasma?

Tags: mathematical-physics

"Plasmas are many-body systems, with enough mobile charged particles to cause some collective behavior ." [M.S. Murillo and J.C.Weisheit Physics Reports 302, 1-65 (1998)].

In the above definition what is meant by "collective behavior" ?

Comment: You can't define the plasma by looking at one particle - the plasma modes are some kind of phenomena that happens to many particles. Think about waves in water -no one H20 molecule "creates" the wave. The wave is a collective behavior of many water molecules. 

Also, it would be best to ask this kind of questions in the physics stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment, I will definitely try it in Physics stackexchange.